# How to make string as raw string in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python,i like to print my string with out considering its special character(i mean raw string)
eg: >>> print 'Hello/npython/tworld'` when i print this its should give o/p as below

```
'Hello\npython\tworld'
```

How can i make my string as raw string
Thanks
Hema

Comment: does prefixing it with `r` work?

Comment: Do you mean to use backslashes as opposed to forward slashes? Like `"Hello\npython\tworld"`?

Comment: Please do not tag with both 'python3.x' and 'python-2.7'. If it's version specific, pick a version. If not, don't use version tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `repr(mystring)` but this will not work if you intend to print with double quotes if initialized that way. It will always use single quotes.